# How to use SQL window function with if conditions to calculate amount?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

**TABLE A**

```
╔═════╦════════════╦════════╗
║ ID  ║    Date    ║ Amount ║
╠═════╬════════════╬════════╣
║ 100 ║ 01/07/2016 ║     50 ║
║ 100 ║ 02/07/2016 ║     60 ║
║ 100 ║ 03/07/2016 ║     70 ║
║ 100 ║ 04/07/2016 ║    100 ║
║ 100 ║ 05/07/2016 ║    450 ║
║ 101 ║ 01/07/2016 ║     50 ║
║ 101 ║ 02/07/2016 ║     70 ║
║ 101 ║ 03/07/2016 ║    150 ║
║ 102 ║ 01/07/2016 ║     30 ║
║ 102 ║ 02/07/2016 ║     40 ║
║ 102 ║ 03/07/2016 ║     60 ║
║ 104 ║ 01/07/2016 ║    200 ║
║ 104 ║ 02/07/2016 ║    300 ║
║ 104 ║ 03/07/2016 ║    500 ║
╚═════╩════════════╩════════╝
```

**TABLE B**

```
╔═════╦════════════╦════════════╗
║ ID  ║    Date    ║ MoveAmount ║
╠═════╬════════════╬════════════╣
║ 100 ║ 01/07/2016 ║        260 ║
║ 100 ║ 02/07/2016 ║        400 ║
║ 101 ║ 02/07/2016 ║         30 ║
║ 101 ║ 03/07/2016 ║         70 ║
║ 103 ║ 02/07/2016 ║         10 ║
║ 104 ║ 02/07/2016 ║        200 ║
╚═════╩════════════╩════════════╝
```

**RESULT**

```
╔═══════════╦═══════════════╦═══════════════╦════════════╗
║ TableA_ID ║ TableA_Amount ║ TableB_Amount ║ Difference ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════════╬═══════════════╬════════════╣
║       100 ║ 400           ║ 400           ║ 0          ║
║       101 ║ 100           ║ 100           ║ 0          ║
║       102 ║ NULL          ║ NULL          ║ NULL       ║
║       104 ║ 300           ║ 200           ║ 100        ║
╚═══════════╩═══════════════╩═══════════════╩════════════╝
```

How to script to get the results I want?

Conditions:

1) If the min date from Table A and Table B is the same, then sum all the amount in Table B MINUS the amount with the min (date) in table B, ELSE sum all the amount from table B.

2) Then compare the total sum with the amount max(date) - min(date) in table A.

Comment: Can you add id 102 to Table A, and id 103 to table B, and adjust the result?

Comment: Please do not poste pictures! Try to set up a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), or  - at least - edit your question and make the sample data copy'n'pasteable...

Comment: I'd use `FIRST_VALUE` and `LAST_VALUE` together with few `GROUP BYs`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think few cross apply can do the trick. and good luck if there is any smarter ways to do that !

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, resOfA, resOfB FROM t1 AS src
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 (resA.maxAmt-resA.minAmt) AS resOfA FROM t1 
    CROSS APPLY (
                    SELECT (SELECT amount FROM t1 WHERE id=src.id AND date = (SELECT max(date) FROM t1 WHERE id=src.id)) AS maxAmt, 
                     (SELECT amount FROM t1 WHERE id=src.id AND date = (SELECT min(date) FROM t1 WHERE id=src.id)) AS minAmt
                ) AS resA
    WHERE src.id = id       
)
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 (resB.sumAmt - resB.minAmt) as resOfB FROM t2
    CROSS APPLY (
                    SELECT (select SUM(amount) FROM t2 WHERE id=src.id) as maxAmt, 
                    (SELECT amount FROM t2 where id=src.id AND date = (SELECT min(date) FROM t2 WHERE id=src.id)) AS minAmt, 
                ) AS resB   
    WHERE src.id = id
)
```

Comment: np :) have fun in SQL !